# Join Table ActiveRecord Invalid Record on Save (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a join table between `freebies` and `subcategories` that is acting up.

(I have an existing join table between `freebies` and `categories` that is absolutely fine, after which the subcategories is modeled, but I can't tell where the difference is that makes it act up.)

Here's my `freebie.rb` model:

```
class Freebie < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :blogs
  has_one_attached :image
  has_one_attached :sample_image
  has_one_attached :t1_image
  has_one_attached :fb_share_image
  has_many_attached :pin_image

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  has_many :categorization_freebies
  has_many :categories, through: :categorization_freebies

  has_many :subcategorization_freebies
  has_many :subcategories, through: :subcategorization_freebies
end
```

And my `subcategory.rb` model:

```
class Subcategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category

  has_many :subcategorization_freebies
  has_many :freebies, through: :subcategorization_freebies
end
```

And finally the `subcategorization_freebie.rb` join table:

```
class SubcategorizationFreebie < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subcategory
  belongs_to :freebie
end
```

So here's the form that's used to create the new freebie (where the error is appearing):

```
<%= simple_form_for(@freebie) do |f| %>
  ...
      <div class="form-group form-check jsItUp">
      <h5>Categories</h5>
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name ) %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group form-check jsItUp">
      <h5>Subcategories</h5>
      <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:subcategory_ids, Subcategory.all, :id, :name ) %>
    </div>
 ...
<% end %>
```

The permissions in the `freebies_controller.rb` controller are like this:

```
def freebie_params
  params.require(:freebie).permit(
    :name,
    :category,
    :short_description,
    :convertkit_url,
    :active,
    :thrivelink,
    
    :image,
    :sample_image,
    :t1_image,
    :fb_share_image,
    :pin_image,

    :top_question,
    :main_heading,
    :main_subheading,
    :t1_short,
    :t1_name,
    :t1_title,
    :t1_long,
    :wyg1,
    :wyg2,
    :wyg3,
    :outcome,
    :outcome_2,

    :ml_id,
    :ml_submit_code,
    :after_download_url,
    :ml_img_track_url,

    category_ids: [],
    subcategory_ids: []
  )
end
```

When the form is submitted it gives an error that says `Validation failed: Subcategories is invalid`.

The server log when this occurs goes like this:

```
app/controllers/freebies_controller.rb:33
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/freebies_controller.rb:33
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)


ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid - Validation failed: Subcategories is invalid:
  app/controllers/freebies_controller.rb:33:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/freebies_controller.rb:32:in `create'
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?  Most of the code was copied directly from the categories relationship...which works just fine.  Help!

Comment: Make sure all your subcategories have a category. To inspect errors on subcategories `fribie.subcategories.map {|s| puts s.errors.full_messages }`

Comment: @Alex Holy cow, how did you do that?  I commented out the relationship between subcategories and categories (in the respective models) and the error disappeared!  Thank you!

Comment: `belongs_to` relationships are required by default. there is nothing else that can invalidate a subcategory. so if you have a subcategory in the database that is missing `category_id` it will be invalid when trying to save it.